# Upload file to Artifactory with Gradle without maven publish

Tags: gradle, artifactory, maven-publish

Is it possible to just upload a file to an Artifactory repository with Gradle and without using the maven-publish plugin?

All I want to do is upload any file to a specific repository location.
Here is the publishing snippet:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
        updatePlugins(MavenPublication) {
            group = 'pluginDescriptor'
            version = ''
            artifact file('README.txt')
        }
    }
}
```

All I want is that the `updatePlugins` entry uploads the `README.txt` to the relative repository path `/pluginDescriptor`.

But `README.txt` gets uploaded as `pluginDescriptor/nip/nip-.txt` where `nip` is the project name.

How can I give a dedicated name without group, artifactID and version?

All examples I could find use the maven-publish plugin which uploades the files according to group, artifactID and version.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

EDIT: There is a direct possibility how the task can be achieved in an platform independen matter: [artifactory-client-java](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-client-java)

Answer (score 2):

A simple `curl` command can do the trick

```
curl -k -u user:pass -T path/to/README.txt http://ip:port/artifactory/repo/group/artifactID/version/
```

Then, a [Gradle version of this command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24059370/2003986) can help you doing the job inside your `build.gradle`

Comment: That would require to install `curl` on each system. Actually, Gradle with its wrapper tries to eliminate system dependencies like this one.

Comment: @koerfer: but I need to upload a file to a relative repo path. This should be a fairly simple and platform independent task.