# How to create or verify ElementRangeIndexes in Marklogic from Flyway script

Tags: spring-boot, marklogic

How to create or verify ElementRangeIndexes in Marklogic from Flyway script. It is a pain to remember the elementRangeIndex to be manually don eon every Marklogic DB we migrate.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the [Flyway gradle plugin](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/gradle/), to execute [ml-gradle](https://developer.marklogic.com/code/ml-gradle/) configuration scripts.

Alternatively, you can use [gradle to execute curl commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058926/gradle-script-to-call-a-rest-web-service-without-any-3rd-party-plugins-any-poin) and create the indexes using the [MarkLogic Management API](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/manage/v2/databases/[id-or-name]/properties) endpoints.

An example of using Curl to define an index taken from [Learning the MarkLogic REST API](https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/rest/):

```
curl -X PUT  --anyauth --user admin:admin --header "Content-Type:application/json" \
-d '{"word-positions": true,
     "element-word-positions": true,
     "range-element-index":
    [ { "scalar-type": "string",
        "namespace-uri": "",
        "localname": "SPEAKER",
        "collation": "http://marklogic.com/collation/",
        "range-value-positions": false,
        "invalid-values": "reject"
      }, 
      { "scalar-type": "string",
        "namespace-uri": "",
        "localname": "affiliation",
        "collation": "http://marklogic.com/collation/",
        "range-value-positions": false,
        "invalid-values": "reject"
      }, 
      { "scalar-type": "int",
        "namespace-uri": "",
        "localname": "contentRating",
        "collation": "",
        "range-value-positions": false,
        "invalid-values": "reject"
      }, 
      { "scalar-type": "unsignedLong",
        "namespace-uri": "http://marklogic.com/filter",
        "localname": "size",
        "collation": "",
        "range-value-positions": false,
        "invalid-values": "reject"
      }, 
      { "scalar-type": "string",
        "namespace-uri": "http://marklogic.com/filter",
        "localname": "Exposure_Time",
        "collation": "http://marklogic.com/collation/",
        "range-value-positions": false,
        "invalid-values": "reject"
      }]}' \
http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/databases/TutorialDB/properties
```

Comment: Thanks Michael  I will surely try this

Comment: Also is there a way to check if the index exists before creating it?

Comment: @stillanovice Same endpoint, [with a GET](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/databases/[id-or-name]/properties) instead of PUT

Comment: I could get the range index data with the admin user. However with an user with rest_writer role I am not able to. Getting the error as below. Wanted to know if there is any specific role taht i can create a user to test as I cannot use the admin user in PRod.